# HTML H5 new line strange behaviour

Tags: html, web, self, self-starting

I was exploring the HTML in freecodecamp's editor and found this strange behaviour of the h tags. Both my code and result are attached in the image.

So, my question is why do these two html h5 tags do not touch each other, why is there a new line?

I get it they are not inline elements but it has already been added to new line, hasn't it? Why one extra line space between them?

Am i missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because browsers have [default styling](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp). In this case the `h5` has a margin which creates the whitespace.

You can check this by inspecting the element via the developer tools `(f12)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It makes sense now, i fixed that by doing * {margin:0px; }

Answer (score 1):

`<h5>` is a Block element. therefore It will be shown as a separate line